# Statistical Algorithms vs Convex Relaxations - Planted Clique

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, approximation-algorithms, clique

I am trying to understand exactly what the lower bounds for the query complexity of statistical algorithms imply for convex relaxations for the planted clique problem ?

A recent paper by [Feldman, Perkins and Vempala](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.4821) builds the connection between Statistical Algorithms and Convex Relaxations by showing that for detecting planted k-CSPs, lower bounds on the complexity of Statistical Algorithms can be translated to lower bounds on the dimension of canonical convex relaxations.

I was wondering if a similar thing can be said about Planted Clique lower bounds for Statistical Algorithms (which were proven [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.1214)). In particular what kind (if any) of lower bounds on Convex Relaxations do these imply?